# In apexcharts, can I show tooltips upon mouse clicking?

Tags: visualization, apexcharts

I would like to show tooltips for my charts on mobile, by allowing the viewer to click the bar of a horizontal bar chart.

Currently the tooltip only shows upon hovering.

In the docs, I can't find options to change this.(https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/ or https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/responsive/)

(I'm using `react-apexcharts`)

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten to finding an answer to this very question . Any chance you found something yet?

Comment: I have not found out any more since posting. I've parked our apex project for now.